# Creating an average test score using the for loop

Tags: c#, for-loop

I am trying to figure out the test score averages up to 4 test scores using a for loop. It seems like I am going over 4 rather than stopping and not sure what I'm doing wrong for it to not display my average. Please advise:

```
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your first test score");

        //variables
        double testScore = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        double average = 0;

        for (int count = 0; count <= 4; count++) // Start the count from 0-4
        {
            //get the total
            average = average + testScore;

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your other test score");
            testScore = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            //Calculate and display 
            Console.WriteLine("The average of your test score is :", average / count);
        }


    }
```

Comment: Change `count <= 4` to `count < 4` since you are starting with `count = 0`.

Comment: since u start at `0` it should be lower than 4 `count < 4`

Comment: As mentioned the `<=` sign is wrong. Also please note that you have already taken the first score outside the loop. So you need to loop only 3 times if you want to average upto 4 times.

Comment: Additionally, you're getting your first test score outside of the for loop. This will make getting the test scores 5 times, not 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your `for` loop is iterating 5 times (i = 0,1,2,3,4(from i=0 to i=4))

```
double average = 0;
double sum = 0;
int numberOfTests = 4;

for (int count = 0; count < numberOfTests; count++) // Start the count from 0-4
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter test score " + count); //Console.WriteLine($"Please enter test score {count}");

    double testScore = 0;

    while(!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out testScore))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a valid number");
    }

    //get the total
    sum = sum + testScore; //or sum += testScore;
}

//Calculate and display (needs to be outside or else gets printed 4 times)
Console.WriteLine("The average of your test score is : " + sum / numberOfTests);
```

Answer (score 2):

If i understand you correctly, you need a *less than* sign not *less than or equal*

```
for (int count = 0; count < 4; count++)
```

The reason why, is you start at 0, i.e the loop iterates `0,1,2,3,4`

or alternatively (and because) you are using the count in division, you should really be starting at 1

```
for (int count = 1; count <= 4; count++)
```

Lastly, you should always check user input for grubby little fingers

```
while(!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out testScore))
    Console.WriteLine("You had one job!);
```

---

[public static bool TryParse (string s, out double result);](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Double_TryParse_System_String_System_Double__)

> Converts the string representation of a number to its double-precision
>   floating-point number equivalent. A return value indicates whether the
>   conversion succeeded or failed.

---

**Full Example**

```
double sum = 0;

for (int count = 0; count <= 4; count++) // Start the count from 0-4
{

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your other test score");
    while(!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out testScore))
        Console.WriteLine("You had one job!);

    sum += testScore;

    //Calculate and display 
    Console.WriteLine($"The average of your test score is : {(sum / (double)count):N2}");
}
```

Comment: Because Div 0 is not possible, I recommend to use int count = 1; count <= 4; count++

Comment: Well thanks to all the suggestions, I was able to figure out how I can get up to 4 test scores. Bigger issue here for me is, why isn't it display my average? What am I doing wrong? Im so confused :(

Comment: @QuangP. make sure you divide by (double)count, otherwise you may get unexpected results

Answer (score 1):

use this code it will solve your issue if any query comment me.

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                 Console.WriteLine("Please enter your first test score");

            //variables
            double testScore = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            double average = 0;

            for (int count = 1; count <= 5; count++) // Start the count from 0-4
            {
                //get the total
                average = average + testScore;

                Console.WriteLine("Please enter your other test score");
                testScore = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                average = average / count;
                //Calculate and display 
                Console.WriteLine("The average of your test score is {0}", average);
            }


            Console.ReadKey();

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Average is not being displayed, because it is never passed to the console.
```

Change the following line:

```
Console.WriteLine("The average of your test score is :", 1);
```

to

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("The average of your test score is : {0}", average/count));
```

or this (assuming that `Console.Writeline` takes care of string formatting implicitly).

```
Console.WriteLine("The average of your test score is : {0}", average / count);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Please try this code:

```
    //variables
    double testScore = 0
    double average = 0;
    double sum = 0;
    for (int count = 1; count <= 4; count++) // Start the count from 0-4
    {
        //get user input
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter test{count} score");
        testScore = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        //now get the sum
        sum = sum + testScore ;
        //Calculate average score
        average = sum / count;
        //Now display the average
        Console.WriteLine("The average of your test score is :", average);
    }
```

> Here are the mistakes you are doing in your code:

1. Running the loop from count = 0 to count = 4 which causes the wrong division. For 1st iteration you have one testScore but count = 0, it will give devide by 0 error.
2. You are taking the testScore input in for loop iteration but you are not calculating average in the same iteration. So, it will never calculate the average with last testScore input.